# Geo IP and country/region/city DB

Tags: geolocation, geo, geoip

Have a nice day!

Could you please advise me free accurate multilingual DB (with frequent updatings) for:

- locate country+region+city (maybe +time zone) by IP (from PHP);
- build dropdown list country/region/city on site (that is, for example, get
  from PHP regions by country and city by region/country). Names of
  countries/regions/cities must be in different languages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaxMind's [GeoIP2 and GeoLite2 databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/whats-new-in-geoip2/) support multiple languages. They currently include German, English, Spanish, French, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, and Simplified Chinese. You can also use the included `geoname_id` to look up the location using [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) to get the location names in other languages.

There is also a [PHP API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) for the format.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it. How can I "get from PHP regions by country and city by region/country"? It is need for "build dropdown list country/region/city on site".

Comment: For country/region/city dropdown list I would recommend you the Geodatasource. (http://www.geodatasource.com/software/world-major-cities-2014-drop-down-list-source-codes)

Comment: A free alternative data source for dropdowns would be [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). It should integrate well with the MaxMind database as MaxMind uses it as a data source.